# Output HTML in XML Attribute

Tags: php, html, xml, hyperlink

I am attempting to display HTML information in an attribute of a XML document.  For example, I somehow want to accomplish the following:

```
Attributes:
 id = "id"
 HTML_Elements = {
 <a href="./link.html">link</a>
 }

 (<something id='id' HTML_Elements='code'></something>)
```

I am wondering if there is some way to accomplish displaying the code directly inside of the attribute without having to link to it on another page.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML attributes may not contain HTML.

See [Chapter 3.3.3 Attribute Value Normalization in the XML 1.0 Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#AVNormalize)